# How do I calculate the arc of a projectile in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-animate

I am creating a game for coursework, two tanks placed on a canvas with input boxes for the initial velocity and angle of the turret, then a button to fire a projectile (currently a div element in the shape of a circle), which calls a function in this case it is fire1. I have messed around for a few days and can't seem to get it to work, "bullet" is my div element.

```
function fire1 () {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
    var bullet = document.getElementById("bullet");
    bullet.style.visibility = "visible"

    var start = null;
    var intialVelocity = velocity1.value
    var angle = angle1.value
    var g = 9.81;
    var progress, x, y;

function step(timestamp) {
    if(start === null) start = timestamp;
    progress = (timestamp - start)/1000;

    x = (turret1.x + 80) + (intialVelocity*progress)
    y = (turret1.y - 400) + (intialVelocity*progress)*Math.sin(angle*toRadians) - (0.5*g*(progress^2));//)

    bullet.style.left = x + "px";
    bullet.style.bottom = y + "px";

    requestAnimationFrame(step);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
```

Below is my css bit of my bullet.

```
#bullet {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 50%;
width: 1em;
height: 1em;
border-radius: 0.5em;
background: red; 
visibility: hidden;
}
```

I am very new to javascript, css and html so help would be very appriciated, I'm trying to incorporate the [trajectory formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QO2Q6.png) will this work? I also want it to be animated so it follows a path when fired. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this a long time ago but forgot to update with solution, below is how x and y are calculated for the trajectory:

```
x = ((turret.anchorX + negative*(initialVelocity*progress*Math.cos(angle*toRadians)))); //x-coordinate for bullet calculated by using x=ut.

y = ((720 - turret.anchorY + (initialVelocity*progress*Math.sin(angle*toRadians)) + (0.5*g*(Math.pow(progress,2))))); //y-coordinate for bullet calculated by usnig ut+0.5at^2.
```